# On Fourier Transform: how to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert complex to float

Tags: python, transform, fft, continuous-fourier

I am trying to compute for the Fourier Transform but keep on getting TypeError: Cannot convert complex to float.

```
def x(t, k):
    return np.exp(-k * t**2) * sy.sin(k*t) * t**4

def get_x_FT(x, f, k):
    x_FT_integrand_real = lambda t: np.real(x(t, k)*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*f*t))
    x_FT_integrand_comp = lambda t: np.imag(x(t, k)*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*f*t))
    x_FT_real = quad(x_FT_integrand_real, -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
    x_FT_comp = quad(x_FT_integrand_comp, -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
    return x_FT_real + 1j*x_FT_comp
```

```
f = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
x_FT = np.vectorize(get_x_FT)(x, f, k=2)
```

the problem arises in the vectorization part. Pls help me by pointing out where i went wrong or tell me how i could resolve this :)))

Comment: I see in the vectorise() you use a function called get_x_FT1. Is it the same as get_x_FT (the one you show us) ?

Comment: yes, it is the same. I already edited that but still gets the same error

Comment: This code works on my computer. Try updating the packages and checking if you haven't redefined x somewhere

Comment: I did change sy to np (check if that helps, even though i doubt it)

Comment: i changed the sy to np and it worked. thank you so much